# Vertical and horizontal center

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-linearlayout, center

I am able to center my image horizontal, but not vertical.. any idea's what might cause this? It should be in the center of the screen. I have also tried android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" but doesn't seem to do the trick...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A LinearLayout does not allow this behavior.  Try a RelativeLayout instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there no way to center an image in a LinearLayout?

Comment: No built-in good way, not.  The LinearLayout acts similarly to HTML - it builds from the top down.  The layout gravity for vertical directions doesn't work because it's too expensive to measure that value constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a LinearLayout at all? You can just use the ImageView with the scaleType=center

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/splash"
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:scaleType="center" />
```

That's your whole xml...

Comment: I'm guessing OP wants to put more than just an image in his view eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use RelativeLayout for such behavior. I can't think of a good way to do it with LinearLayout. Additionally, you can try the Graphical Layout (depends on the editor you are using).

Answer (score 0):

I used two images in invisible mode just for create space.
 
Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fake"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fake"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```